Is it possible to have lower ECE but worse reliable curve?
I am new to the calibration concept for classification. I have tried temperature scaling on my model's results. However, after applying temperature scaling, the reliable curve got worse despite getting lower ECE. Here are my results:
ECE before calibration: 0.044
ECE after calibration: 0.028

I thought that since ECE shows how well a model's results are calibrated, the lower ECE should lead to a better reliability curve. Is there any problem with my results, or it's not odd to achieve them? I really appreciate it if you could explain why is this happening.
